# Migrate function C++ with pointers to C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++

I have a function in C++ that returns pointer values​​:

```
fPosFirst( int &aId, char *aNname, char *aDirectory );
```

My syntax in c# is:

```
fPosFirst(ref int aId,  String aNname,  String aDirectory);
```

the function returns the id but not the string parameters that anyone knows?

Comment: Can you show us how you do in C# to call the C++ function?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the native function does not "return pointers" but writes characters to the memory locations specified by aNname and aDirectory, you should be able to pass a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) with a proper capacity to the native function:

```
void fPosFirst(ref int aId, StringBuilder aNname, StringBuilder aDirectory);
```

*Usage:*

```
var aId = 0;
var aNname = new StringBuilder(260);
var aDirectory = new StringBuilder(260);

fPosFirst(ref aId, aNname, aDirectory);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the parameters to be used for returning values then mark them as [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx).

E.g.

```
fPosFirst(ref int aId,  out string aNname,  out string aDirectory);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the string parameters `ref` or `out` if you want to assign to them within the method and have those values available outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `out` keyword before parameters names ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). But actually this is not good practice in C#